# Perform and test random demand generation with Vectorize for data.table

Tags: r, testing, random, data.table, vectorization

I have a `data.table` *inv* containing demand data per period and article and another `data.table` *arts* containing information about the gamma distribution function of demand for each article (with shape and rate parameters).

I want to create all random demand in one step for all periods and all articles and I am not sure whether my code does it properly.

```
library(data.table)
artID <- LETTERS[1:5]
inv <- CJ(period=1:10, ar=artID, d=0); setkey(inv,period,ar)
arts <- data.table(ar=artID, shape=seq(0.6,1,0.1), rate=seq(6,10)); setkey(arts,ar)

set.seed(1000)

vrgamma <- Vectorize(rgamma, USE.NAMES = TRUE, SIMPLIFY=TRUE)
inv[,d:=vrgamma(10, shape=arts[,shape], rate=arts[,rate])]
# Warning message: In `[.data.table`(inv, , `:=`(d, vrgamma(10, shape = arts[, shape],  :
# 5 column matrix RHS of := will be treated as one vector
```

So I get a warning, but I have random numbers in every period for every article. But I don't know whether they are the in the right place. And since it is random, I cannot look at the values and see whether they are right.

So here are my questions

1. Do you think my solution works?
2. Can you tell me how to test whether my solution works?
3. Can I get rid of the warning with `as.vector` without side effects?
4. Can you think of a better way to tackle my problem?

Comment: I think you're looking for `inv[arts, on="ar", d := rgamma(.N, shape, rate), by=.EACHI]`. Have a look at the vignettes to get a sense for the syntax https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started This is an example of a "merge assign" (that's what I call it anyways).

Comment: thanks, that's it. It's really worthwile to stay up to date with the data.table evolution, I didn't know about secondary keys